# Updating/Creating Custom Listview on PostExecute inside a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, bluetooth

So I have a Sections Pager Application in Android. On my fourth fragment, I run an asynctask that connects to a device via bluetooth and updates a custom list that I created (supposedly) However, the list either updates late or doesn't update at all. I'm not exactly sure what to do on the postexecute to allow update so I updated it outside of the asynctask.

**Code is below:**

```
     public class FourthFragment extends Fragment {
    private WeakReference<getBeacons> getBeaconTaskWeakRef;
    ArrayList<ArtInfo> ArtList = new ArrayList<>();
    ;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
        startNewBeaconsAsyncTask();
    }

    ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> artists = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> years = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> images = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ArtList.size(); i++) {
            titles.add(ArtList.get(i).getArtTitle());
            artists.add(ArtList.get(i).getArtistName());
            years.add(ArtList.get(i).getYear());
            int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(ArtList.get(i).getImageFilename(), "drawable", "com.acuart.acumen.acuart");
            images.add(resID);
        }
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_list, container, false);
        ListView byTitleList = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.byTitleList);
        byTitleList.setAdapter(new titleList(getActivity(), R.layout.custom_list, titles));
        return v;
    }

    private void startNewBeaconsAsyncTask() {
        getBeacons newbeacons = new getBeacons(this);
        this.getBeaconTaskWeakRef = new WeakReference<getBeacons>(newbeacons);
        newbeacons.execute();
    }

    class titleList extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        public titleList(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<String> objects) {
            super(context, resource, objects);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = ((Activity) getContext()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_list, null);
            TextView title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.row_title);
            TextView artist = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.row_artist);
            TextView year = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.row_year);
            ImageView image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.row_image);

            title.setText(titles.get(position));
            artist.setText(artists.get(position));
            year.setText(years.get(position));
            image.setBackgroundResource(images.get(position));
            return v;
        }
    }

    private class getBeacons extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private WeakReference<FourthFragment> fragmentWeakReference;

        private getBeacons(FourthFragment fragment) {
            this.fragmentWeakReference = new WeakReference<FourthFragment>(fragment);
        }

        ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        int artCount = 0;
        SQLHelper markerDBHelper = new SQLHelper(context);

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog.setMessage("Loading, please wait...");
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            checkBluetooth();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }       //processing bluetooth data and creating a query for database return.
}
```

Any help/comments/ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Where is the `AsyncTask` which updates the list?

Comment: I suggest that you follow the common Java convention of naming classes starting with an uppercase letter.

Answer (score 1):

Code in `onPostExecute()` runs on the UI thread, so you should be able to update your list adapter there.

I'm a bit confused by your question, are you saying that it takes a long time for `onPostExecute()` to run? Did you have your code in there to update the list, and then moved it out because `onPostExecute()` took too long to be called?

Do you have a bunch of other async tasks running?

*I didn't have time to test compile/test this, so there could very well be some syntax mistakes, but this is just to give you an idea*

In `titleList` add a method to update the data backing the adapter list so:

```
public void updateAdapterData(ArrayList<String> newData) {
    clear();
    addAll(newData);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And the async task could do something like this

```
private titleList mTitleList; //Set this in your onCreateView

private class getBeacons extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<String>> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog.setMessage("Loading, please wait...");
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Object> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //If checkbluetooth returns a list..
        return checkBluetooth();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> newList) {
        mTitleList.updateAdapterData(newList)
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your response! My question is that I create the custom listview in onCreateView. By the time the asynctask finishes, the view was already created, so I would have to switch tabs to see the updated list, but by then it has already ran another asynctask so I run into a loop. Sometimes it doesn't update at all. My question relates to what your comment is. How can I update or create the adapter on Postexecute?

Comment: So I wouldn't have to inflate the view again?

Comment: I think it would be better to keep a reference to the adapter and change the array list rather than creating a new adapter each time the data changes.

Comment: Hello Code-Apprentice, thank you for replying as well. But I'm a new programmer and I'm confused. How would you keep a reference to a custom list inside the asynctask?

Comment: Code-Apprentice has the right idea with how to properly update an adapter, I was just make a quick solution. I'll update my answer with a  better example

Comment: Hello @markreed49! I tried modifications to my code following your example and did not get a syntax error but a run-time error. 
    Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void  com.acuart.acumen.acuart.MainActivity$FourthFragment$titleList.updateAdapterData(java.util.ArrayList)' on a null object reference

Comment: You need to instantiate your titleList still, like you did above in you onCreateView

    mTitleList = new titleList(getActivity(), R.layout.custom_list, titles);
    byTitleList.setAdapter(mTitleList);

Answer (score 1):

At First set the ListView adapter as follows:

```
titleList adapter=new titleList(getActivity(), R.layout.custom_list, titles));
byTitleList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

After doing the background task if you get an List of "titles", then in "onPostExecute" method  you can do the following:-

```
private class getBeacons extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<String> > {

    ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>();

    private getBeacons() {

    }



    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {

        //call a method for assigning values to titles
        return titles;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> titles) {

        //Now assign this arraylist referrence to your actual titles arraylist 

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to update the `ArrayList` in your `titleList` adapter and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter. I suggest doing this with a `setList()` method in the `titleList` class. You also need to keep a reference of the adapter where it is accessible by your `AsyncTask`.